# update entire column with different values

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update `tags` column so each cell has the content like this:
`2-5-1-14-5`
or
`3-9-14-19-23`
or simmilar (five integers, in range from 1-25).

`id` column is not consecutive from 1-117, but anyway min `id` is 1 and max 117.

```
$arr = [];
$str = '';
$id = 1;
for ($x = 1; $x <= 25; $x++){
    array_push($arr, $x);
}
while ($id < 117) {
shuffle($arr);
array_splice($arr, 5, 25);
foreach ($arr as $el){
    $str .= $el . '-';
}
$str = rtrim($str,'-');
$db->query("update posts set tags = '" . $str . "' where id = " . $id);
$id += 1;
}
```

I'm not sure how to describe the final result, but it seems that the majority of cells are written multiple times.

Any help ?

Comment: What makes you think that the majority of cells are written multiple times?

Comment: You can replace `foreach ($arr as $el) { $str .= $el . '-'; } $str = rtrim($str,'-');` by `$str = implode('-',$arr);`.

Comment: I don't understand your data, but if you need to access individual numbers within that hyphenated list then your current approach is bound for failure.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, because tha majority of cells has this content - `18-10-2-17-1917-2-19-18-1019-2-17-10-1819-10-2-17-...`

Comment: You need to reset `$str`, like so: `$str = '';` before your `foreach` loop. Anyway, Tim is right, your database doesn't seem normalized, that's a bad idea.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I get the individual numbers by php `explode` function. It seems ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine my comments into one piece of code:

```
$full = range(1, 25);
$id   = 1;
while ($id < 117) {
    shuffle($full);
    $section = array_slice($full, 0, 5);
    $str     = implode('-',$section);
    $db->query("update posts set tags = '" . $str . "' where id = " . $id);
    $id += 1;
}
```

So the reset of `$str` is not needed anymore since I have inserted the `implode()` where it seems functional. The other bits of code could probably be improved.

Two warnings:

- Using PHP variables directly in queries is not a good idea. Please use parameter binding. This particular piece of code might not be vulnerable to SQL-injection but if you do the same elsewhere it might be.
- Your database doesn't seem to be normalized. This might cause trouble for you in the long run when you expand your application.

Comment: Thanks, I see the point. I tried and now all cells have value combined only of this five integers  - `13-9-11-6-12`, without `1-5-7... for example, in any cell.

Comment: The problem was the `array_splice()`. This should now work as you want.

Comment: ok. I also tried `$arr[] = shuffle($arr);` integers are changed, but only another set of five of them,  repeatdidly, without others.

Comment: with your new code only five rows have content, other cells are empty.

Comment: Haha, yes, that makes sense... `array_splice()` eats the array. It needs to be changed to `array_slice()` which doesn't eat the array.

Comment: Good. I added another simplification with `range()`.